# android communication between main and backgroung threads

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I need update some files in my application from the internet. For this purposes I can start new thread which check updates on web server and signal my application about new updates.
below there is skeleton of my update process. This code based on explanations placed  [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Main Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks{
     TextView tvStatus;
     Button btnSend;
     private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";
     private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

        // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
        // retained across a configuration change.
        if (mTaskFragment == null) {
          mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
          fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(int msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tvStatus.setText(""+msg);
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tere are new updates for You", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
    
}
```

Work Fragment to run update thread:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
     private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
     Handler h;
    static interface TaskCallbacks {
        
        void onPostExecute(int msg);
      }
     @Override
      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
      }

      /**
       * This method will only be called once when the retained
       * Fragment is first created.
       */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);
        h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
              mCallbacks.onPostExecute(msg.what);
          };
        };
        ////////////////////
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

              try {
               
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
                while (true)//this is daemon thread
                {
                    if(this.checkUpddates())
                    {
                        h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);// sleeping can be very long
                }
              

              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

            private boolean checkUpddates() {
                //here check updates on internet
                try{
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);// emulate check updates work
                
                }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
                                return true;
            }
            
          });
        t.setDaemon(true);
          t.start();
        
      }

      /**
       * Set the callback to null so we don't accidentally leak the 
       * Activity instance.
       */
      @Override
      public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
      }
     
}
```

XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
     android:id="@+id/tvMain" />
```

This code work fine in case when I try rotate screen. Also it work fine in case I work in another activity than Main Activity and update thread return its result to Handler's handleMessage method.
I want to ask android guru to advice me if I on the right way or perhaps there are better ways to perform this task? Are there any pitfalls in my code?

Comment: ask the same @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want a code review

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'd go for a different approach. If what you need is to refresh a feed (similar to Tweeter) I'd fire a single request `onCreate()` using `AsyncTask` for the background operation. In case you need to automatically refresh the data every 20 seconds, then just add a timer to re-fire the `AsyncTask`. That way you can communicate with the UI Thread inside `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()`

If what you need is a persistent connection cause you're sending and retrieving real time data (for example a Chat app), then you may wanna go for a `Socket` implementation, using a `Thread` similar to what you are doing.

In both cases, I see the use of a `Fragment` unnecessary, but I might be wrong on this one.

Comment: Fragment needed to work correctly in case user rotate screen during asynkTask working. See http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html Perhaps there are any other approaches?

Comment: Sorry I'm not saying using `Fragment` is wrong, I meant I prefer not using them. But the approach is the same whether you use or not a retained Fragment. Just instantiate the `AsyncTask` inside the fragment, and implement the background logic on its `doInBackground()`. Finally use its `onPostExecute()` to execute code on the UI Thread